# Xamarin AXML troubles

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Good day. I try to use this https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/ , but i have some problems.

I try to implement XAML(below) into AXML(below too). But i have exceptions with this implementation of OnCreate() method for CameraApp.Droid.MainActivity.

Please, help me understand AXML usage in android app, because i don't understand how it should be implemented.

[Project looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X1XN.jpg)

I need to implement something like code below(XAML) in AXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cameraApp="clr-namespace:CameraApp;assembly=CameraApp.Droid"
             x:Class="CameraApp.CameraPage">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <cameraApp:CameraButton Grid.Row="0"/>
    <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
      <Label Text="gallery" />
    </ScrollView>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

I try to rewrite it into AXML (Main.axml in CameraApp.Droid)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <CameraButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CameraApp.App.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CameraApp
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {
            MainPage = new CameraPage();
        }
    }
}
```

CameraApp.CameraButton.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CameraApp
{
    public class CameraButton : Button { }
}
```

CameraButtonRenderer.cs:

```
using CameraApp;
using CameraApp.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CameraButton), typeof(CameraButtonRenderer))]
namespace CameraApp.Droid
{
    public class CameraButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                var nativeButton = Control;
                nativeButton.Click += delegate
                {
                    SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.LightGreen);
                };
                nativeButton.LongClick += delegate
                {
                    SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CameraApp.Droid.MainActivity.cs:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;

namespace CameraApp.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = "CameraApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can follow an example like the following:

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Camera

Comment: @JonDouglas thanks

Comment: Please include the exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin [Media plugin](https://components.xamarin.com/view/mediaplugin) lets you access the camera directly from your Forms project without needing to write custom platform renderers.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But if i have button in XAML, it possible to take photo directly to specified folder, without open built-in camera?